# Vagrant + Virtualbox creates virtual machine on network drive - Windows 7

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, vagrant

Vagrant by default downloads .box image to VAGRANT_HOME directory, then imports it into VirtualBox. VirtualBox by default uses ~/VirtualBox VMs directory to store it's image.

My problem is that ~/ is on network drive (extremely slow)

When I'm creating new box manually I can specify where to create it, but can't get same behaviour vith vagrant up.

I've tried setting VBoxManage.exe setproperty machinefolder  but it's not working.

Only workaround I've found is to start VirtualBox and change default machine folder in preferences. Problem with this solution is that I always have to run VirtulBox app before I  run vagrant up

Any ideas how to fix it?

I'm using Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

Vagrant doesn't currently offer a way to configure the directory for VirtualBox VMs. (For the VMware providers you can set `VAGRANT_VMWARE_CLONE_DIRECTORY`.)

The "Default Machine Folder" setting in "General" tab of the VirtualBox preferences should anyway be used for new VMs once it's set. Maybe you spun up already existing VMs, or reseted the value with some `setproperty machinefolder` call?